# LabVIEW has pink breakpoints instead of red

Tags: labview

I'm trying to recall what it means when you try to place a breakpoint on a wire in LabVIEW, and it is pink colored instead of red. I am calling the LabVIEW VI in TestStand if that matters at all.

[image]

Thanks,

Comment: What version of Labview is it?

Answer (score 3):

Usually it is displayed like this when one opens clone of reetrant VI. So original VI has breakpoint, and its clone also has breakpoint - but it is kind of dimmed because when you will remove it, anyway it will be there (because breakpoint then should be removed from the "original" VI).
Another option could be that VI is loaded from different context, thus you can not edit it.